# MySQL Select 2 items from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select 2 of the same item from multiple tables. Here's a run down of my data.

Items

```
Item ID    Item name
1          Item1
2          Item2
3          Item3
4          Item4
```

Item Pairs

```
Item ID 1  Item ID 2
4          1
4          3
3          1
4          2
```

The pairs are linked via foreign key.

What I need to be able to do is select the 2 item names based on the item pair ids. I got as far as selecting only 1 of them with the below query but have not been able to select more than that.

```
SELECT item_name FROM items, item_pairs WHERE item_pairs.item_id_1 = item.item_id
```

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one by rejoining the items table

```
SELECT 
  i.item_name,
  i2.item_name 
FROM
  items i 
  JOIN item_pairs ip 
    ON ip.item_id_1 = i.item_id 
  JOIN items i2 
    ON ip.item_id_2 = i2.item_id 
GROUP BY ip.item_id_1,
  ip.item_id_2
```

Comment: Thank you very, this worked perfectly! I added ip.item_pair_id, to the GROUP BY so that it listed in order of the item paid ids. Thank you very much!